# DataGridView ComboBox Column: Change cell value after selection from dropdown is made?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have setup a ComboBoxColumn for my DataGridView and set its selectable values from an enumeration. It mostly works as I would like with the following exception.

Whenever I click the dropdown arrow and then select one of the enum values, it remains in sort of a "intermediate" state where the CellValueChanged event isn't triggered. I need to focus on another cell or another control for the event to fire.

I also have an event handler for the DataGridView's Leaving event which "validates" the contents by making sure that no cell is empty.

So, if I create a row and fill all the cells and come to the (currently blank) ComboBox column, change it to a value, and then click a Run button; my error dialog pops up because the ComboBox selection wasn't "saved".

How can I get around this? Is there a way that after I select a value from the drop down it automatically "sets" the value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event and force a commit edit on the grid:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It most certainly did! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I would extend Moop's answer by checking the cell type instead of the column type.

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;

void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentCell is DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: `EndEdit()` save my life. Thanks Bioukh

Comment: @Bioukh
To receive changes to the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` field, I created an event handler:
`private void Dgv_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{dgv.CommitEdit (DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
dgv.EndEdit ();
    iNumerator ++;
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert (0, "*** Event_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged_4 -" + iNumerator + "\ r \ n"); // ++ Add a line to the beginning
}`

Comment: @Bioukh In `textBox1.Text` I get the result:
`*** Event_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged_4 - 2
*** Event_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged_4 - 1`
In other words, the event fires two times.
**Question:** is it correct that the event triggers two times?
Can the event be triggered once?
Or is this not a fundamental problem?

Comment: By committing the current cell edition, this function will change the current cell dirty state (ie IsCurrentCellDirty), so it will indeed trigger again this event.

Answer (score 6):

I would extend ionden's answer by checking if the `DataGridViewColumn` is the type of `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` before forcing the `CommitEdit`. This will prevent other `DataGridViewColumn` objects from committing too early.

```
    dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;

    void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn col = dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
        if (col is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        {
            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event fixed mouse interaction for this issue, but it breaks keyboard interaction - using F4 then up/down arrow, every arrow click results in a dirty state change and commits the edit. The solution I found, was to grab the "DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl" when it's created, and attach a DropDownClosed event to it. This works for keyboard and mouse interaction. In this example, we extended DataGridView so every instance would inherit this functionality:

```
    protected override void OnEditingControlShowing(DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl control = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.DropDownClosed -= ComboBoxDropDownClosedEvent;
            control.DropDownClosed += ComboBoxDropDownClosedEvent;
        }
        base.OnEditingControlShowing(e);
    }

    void ComboBoxDropDownClosedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = CurrentCell as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
        if ((cell != null) && cell.IsInEditMode)
        {
            CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            EndEdit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, the value won't stick until the focus has left the row entirely. In that case, the only way to force the current edit to end is to end it on the whole binding context:

```
mGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
mGridView.BindingContext[mGridView.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit(); // <<===
```

I found this tip [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_21954570.html).

Answer (score 1):

I spend like two hours searching for an error because I did not notice that the cell value does not get saved if it´s not defocused, or better to say I just noticed that the cell is not defocused because the combobox whited out while saving(btn event).
Not only that, the EditOnEnter-Mode prevails that most other methods shown above work. The reason to use EditOnEnter is that when you use a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, you have to click two times to open the dropdown if you do not set EditMode to EditOnEnter.

`this.dataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2;
this.dataGridView.EndEdit();
this.dataGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;`

I hope this helps. It cost me around two hours wondering why the value in the object is not the same then shown on the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding my answer as a follow-up to the discussion that has already occurred.  I was trying to build a DataGridView that had different comboboxes per row.  They also had to be responsive to a single click.  And, when the selection was made, another cell in the row needed to be changed according to the combobox selection.  The change needed to happen as soon as the selection was made.  My main problem, like the OP's, was the change wouldn't happen until the combobox lost focus.

So, here is a full working minimal example of such a DataGridView.  I had to bring it down to a minimum because getting all my requirements to work at the same time was tricky.  Several SO posts went into making this, and I will update my post with references later.  But for now, here goes...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestDGV
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Panel panel2;
    private DataGridView TestGrid;

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panel2
        // 
        this.panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
        this.panel2.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(661, 407);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //basic grid properties
        TestGrid = new DataGridView();
        TestGrid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        TestGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        TestGrid.Name = "TestGrid";
        TestGrid.ReadOnly = false;
        TestGrid.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;

        //Event handlers
        TestGrid.DataBindingComplete += TestGrid_DataBindingComplete;
        TestGrid.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += TestGrid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;
        TestGrid.CellValueChanged += TestGrid_CellValueChanged;

        //columns
        var textCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        textCol.HeaderText = "Text";
        textCol.Name = "Text";
        textCol.DataPropertyName = "Text";
        textCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        TestGrid.Columns.Add(textCol);

        var comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        comboCol.HeaderText = "ComboBox";
        comboCol.Name = "ComboBox";
        comboCol.AutoComplete = true;
        comboCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        TestGrid.Columns.Add(comboCol);

        var resultCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        resultCol.HeaderText = "Result";
        resultCol.Name = "Result";
        resultCol.DataPropertyName = "Result";
        resultCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        TestGrid.Columns.Add(resultCol);

        //Bind the data
        Datum.TestLoad();
        TestGrid.DataSource = Datum.Data;

        panel2.Controls.Add(TestGrid);
    }

    void TestGrid_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
            return;

        var row = TestGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        var cell = row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (cell is DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        {
            var val = cell.Value as string;
            var datum = row.DataBoundItem as Datum;
            datum.Current = val;
            row.Cells["Result"].Value = datum.Result;
            TestGrid.InvalidateRow(e.RowIndex);
        }
    }


    void TestGrid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(TestGrid.CurrentCell is DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        {
            TestGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            TestGrid.EndEdit();
        }
    }

    void TestGrid_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in TestGrid.Rows)
        {
            var datum = row.DataBoundItem as Datum;
            if (datum == null)
                return;

            var cell = row.Cells["ComboBox"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            if (cell.DataSource == null)
            {
                cell.DisplayMember = "KeyDisplayValue";
                cell.ValueMember = "KeyValue";
                cell.DataSource = (row.DataBoundItem as Datum).Combo;
                cell.Value = (row.DataBoundItem as Datum).Current;
            }
        }
        TestGrid.DataBindingComplete -= TestGrid_DataBindingComplete;
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public static void TestLoad()
        {
            var t1 = new Triplet[] {
                     new Triplet("1", "World", "Everyone" ),
                     new Triplet("2", "Charlie", "Friend of Algernon" ),
                     new Triplet("3", "Lester", "Phenomenal programmer" ),
            };
            var t2 = new Triplet[] {
                     new Triplet("1", "World", "Everyone" ),
                     new Triplet("4", "Mary", "Wife of George Bailey" ),
                     new Triplet("3", "Lester", "Phenomenal programmer" ),
            };
            Data.Add(new Datum("hello, ", t1.ToList()));
            Data.Add(new Datum("g'bye, ", t2.ToList()));
        }
        public static List<Datum> Data = new List<Datum>();

        public Datum(string text, List<Triplet> combo)
        {
            this._text = text;
            this._combo = combo.ToDictionary<Triplet,string>(o => o.KeyValue);
            this.Current = combo[0].KeyValue;
        }

        private string _text;
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return _text;
            }
        }

        private Dictionary<string, Triplet> _combo;
        public List<Triplet> Combo
        {
            get
            {
                return _combo.Values.ToList();
            }
        }

        private string _result;
        public string Result
        {
            get
            {
                return _result;
            }
        }

        private string _current;
        public string Current
        {
            get
            {
                return _current;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != null && _combo.ContainsKey(value))
                {
                    _current = value;
                    _result = _combo[value].Description;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Triplet
    {
        public string KeyValue { get; set; }
        public string KeyDisplayValue { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Triplet(string keyValue, string keyDisplayValue, string description)
        {
            KeyValue = keyValue;
            KeyDisplayValue = keyDisplayValue;
            Description = description;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Droj for the tip about EndCurrentEdit, which I needed to make it work for me.
This is what I ended up doing to instantly commit DataGridViewComboBoxColumns and DataGridViewCheckBoxColumns:

```
private void dataGridViewEnumerable_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
  if (dataGridView == null || dataGridView.CurrentCell == null)
    return;
  var isComboBox = dataGridView.CurrentCell is DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
  if ((isComboBox || dataGridView.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) 
    && dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit) 
    && isComboBox && dataGridView.EndEdit())
    dataGridView.BindingContext[dataGridView.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved the issue

```
Private Sub dgvEcheancier_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgvEcheancier.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
        nbreClick += 1
            With dgvEcheancier
                Select Case .CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
                Case 9
                    Dim col As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = .Columns(9)
                    If TypeOf (col) Is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Then
                        dgvEcheancier.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
                        If nbreClick = 2 Then
                            MessageBox.Show("y" & "val=" & .CurrentCell.Value)
                            nbreClick = 0
                        End If
                    End If

            End Select
            End With
```

Comment: Please watch the c# tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
    ComboBox cmbMiCtrl=(ComboBox)dataGridView1.EditingControl;
    string Valor= cmbMiCtrl.Text;
    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I saw : It won't work if you choose :
`GridView.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;`

Answer (score -1):

You should use  CellValueChanged which fires the change event on grid and inside the event you should commit changes and leave the control in order to save the item after it is selected.

```
    private void FilterdataGrid_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    FilterdataGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);      

    FilterdataGrid.EndEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.LeaveControl);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you try and add some context and explanation to your answer so future users can benefit from it? Answering with plain code is far less likely to serve as a more general answer for future users. Take a look at [answer] for more information.

Comment: This causes a stack overflow on CommitEdit (for Unbound data).