# Validate DataGridViewComboBoxCell when user changes to a new value

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

We have a column in our DataGridView for which the user can select a value from a combobox (`DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`). We have some validation logic for the selection (overridden `OnCellValidating`).

The annoying thing is, the user has to click elsewhere after making their drop-down selection in the combo box, before the validation happens for that cell.  I've tried committing the edit as soon as the selected index changes (see below), but the validation is still not firing until the cell loses focus. I've also tried using `EndEdit()` rather than `CommitEdit()`.

Is there a way to get the validation to fire as soon as the user selects an item in the combo box?

```
    protected override void OnEditingControlShowing(DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Validate selection as soon as user clicks combo box item.
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null)
        {
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= combo_SelectedIndexChanged;
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(combo_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }

        base.OnEditingControlShowing(e);
    }

    void combo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        this.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }

    protected override void OnCellValidating(DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        // (our validation logic) ...
    }
```

Comment: What you want to do kind of goes against the UI validation guidelines. Validation normally happens when you leave the row. This way you can commit multiple changes in one 'transaction'. If you need immediate validation, create a data form, and have all custom validation you want there.

Comment: In this case, though, we don't have any notion of "entering" or "leaving" a row; there's just the combo box and the associated items. It feels strange to have to not only click the item in the combo box, but also click "off" the cell to validate the input. Users may be surprised when they make a selection, no errors, then click a different combo box's row and _then_ get dinged. If we can commit and end an edit when the user clicks an item, why not validate then as well for consistency with _this_ look and feel?

Comment: `there's just the combo box and the associated items` please explain this part.

Comment: We're not using the DGV to edit rows in a DataTable; it's used more to present a  list of items (one column in the DGV) for which the user can set a property (the other column in the DGV). So the DGV has columns like "Foo" "Foo Type" where "Foo Type" is a combobox. You can see why in this presentation it feels weird to have "row-based" editing requiring you to pick the Foo Type and then click somewhere else to validate it.

Comment: Validity of "Foo Type" depends on what? If it's some "Foo", then it's not different from a regular row based editing. Once you change "Foo Type" and it does not correspond to "Foo", you may decide to change "Foo" as your next step. And not necessarily the other way around, all the time. You don't need UI scream at you before you finish. It's about those guidelines I was talking about. Unless I misunderstood your intent. In this case please elaborate further. It's preferable that you outline your requirements as close to the subject with possible. Please refrain from abstract "Foo" if you can.

Comment: [DataGridView.CellValidating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx) event `occurs when a cell loses input focus`. Would you be able to call your validation logic from `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler?

Comment: @JacobSeleznev: We may simply do that, if there's no way to make CellValidating occur on demand. Seems weird to have to work around the built-in cell validation but I guess they designed it very specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate tab key to force the cell to lose focus:

```
    private void combo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I expect to get the validation to fire as soon as the user 
        //selects an item in the combo box but the validation 
        //is not firing until the cell loses focus
        //simulate tab key to force the cell to lose focus
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        SendKeys.Send("+{TAB}");
    }
```

Comment: How do you subscribe this event handler to a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` or `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`?

Comment: Handle the `EditingControlShowing` event of DataGridView.

Comment: That would just cause it to lose focus right after gaining it, correct? Anyway, there is a very simple solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9609103/60067).